# Undefined method `streets' for nil:NilClass, Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a City Model:

```
class Geo::City < Smth
self.table_name = 'cities_table'
has_many :streets, class_name: "Geo::Street", primary_key: :geo_code, foreign_key: :geo_code
```

So, when I try in the console, I get the result needed, which is all the streets in the city

```
    Geo::City.find_by(geo_code: '09679117').streets

    => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy
    [#<Geo::Street geo_code: "09679117", city_name: "Bergtheim", street_name: "Good Street", geometry: "0106000020E61000000100000001030000000122200090000...">,
#<Geo::Street geo_code: "09679117", city_name: "Bergtheim", street_name: "Bad Street", geometry: "0106000020E61000000100000001030000000100000009111...">]
```

So, to search for a City I have used select2 and it works just perfect. The idea is, I select Berlin, on submit I get 15 first Streets in Berlin. I thought in my controller I can basically do the same, I did in the console to get the Streets listed. I am using Ransack for this

```
def filter
        if params[:q].present? && params[:q][:geo_code_eq].present?
            @city = Geo::City.find_by(geo_code: params[:q][:geo_code_eq]) 
            @collection = [["#{@city}", "#{params[:q][:geo_code_eq]}"]]
        end

        @streets = @city.streets.limit(15)
        @q = @streets.ransack(params[:q])
    end
```

Well this return the error I put in the title "Undefined method `streets' for nil:NilClass". What am I doing wrong? P.S. all names are fake, just to give an impression.

Comment: are you getting the correct values in `geo_code_eq` ? i think it won't work the way you did

Comment: I had to define params[:q][:ags8_id_eq] = xxx, but still not getting the streets in the result, but I guess, it's another problem...

Comment: You are not getting @city that's why you are getting error

Comment: could you suggest a solution or tell me why?

Comment: Could you please add logs in question which params are you passing?

Comment: After I did some channges it seemed to work, but here is the problem I am getting right now : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624163/ransack-search-form-replaces-search-with-placeholder