# Ransack search form replaces search with "Placeholder"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, ransack

My ransack serach form for cities somehow has a "default city" and even if i click on submit and params are present in the url, I still come back to a select with a default city, which also affects the search results. Here is my select (I work with select2).

```
= search_form_for @search, url: filter_path do |f|
    .columns.is-centered{style: 'padding-top: 100px;'}
        .column.is-half
            = f.select(:geo_code_eq, options_for_select(@collection, (params[:q][:geo_code_eq].nil? ? '' : params[:q][:geo_code_eq])), {:include_blank => true}, {class: "city-select2 select-input" })
            = f.submit "Search"
```

I guess it has smth. to do with collection, but I couldn't find out, what's exactly bringing this default city. So this part of controller:

```
def filter
 @city_list = city_list
 params[:q] ||= {}
 params[:q][:geo_code_eq] = @city_list[0][1]
 if params[:q].present? && params[:q][:geo_code_eq].present?
  @city = Geo::City.find_by(geo_code: params[:q][:geo_code_eq]) 
  @collection = [["#{@city}", "#{params[:q][:geo_code_eq]}"]]
end
    @search = @city.streets.ransack(params[:q])
    @streets = @search.result
end
```

Comment: to start, always use TWO spaces. you use 4 spaces in the view, 1 space in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

This was putting the placeholder in the select params[:q][:geo_code_eq] = @city_list[0][1], basically saying there is always first sity in the list to be places in my select. I replaces it with an empty collection and a case where no street is to show just yet using rails .none and it wored just fine.